# Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python very slow

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've written a program in Python that finds all the prime numbers below a given number (*n*), and sums them up (to answer **Project Euler's Problem 10**). To solve the problem, I need to add up all primes below 2,000,000. My program works, but seems very inefficient (when *n* = 2,000,000 , it won't show the answer even after 30 minutes). I have found another program that is much and much faster, though I can't seem to find out what makes mine slower than the one I've found. Here are the two programs:

**Slow program (the one I've written):**

```
def print_sum(n):

    prime_array = {}
    sum = 0

    for i in range(2, n+1):
        prime_array[i] = 1

    prime_array[0] = 0
    prime_array[1] = 0

    for j in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if prime_array[j] == 1:
            for k in range(2, n + 1):
                prime_array[j*k] = 0

    for x in prime_array:
        if prime_array[x] == 1:
            sum = sum + x

    print sum

print_sum(2000000)
```

**Fast program:**

```
n = 2000000
prime_array = [True] * n
sum = 0

def mark(prime_array, x):
    for i in xrange(x+x, len(prime_array), x):
        prime_array[i] = False


for x in xrange(2, int(len(prime_array)** .5) + 1):
    if prime_array[x]: mark(prime_array, x)

for y in xrange(2, n):
    if prime_array[y]:
        sum = sum + y

print sum
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read up on the difference between `xrange` and `range`. Check the `limit` and the `step`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
        for k in range(2, n + 1):
            prime_array[j*k] = 0
```

Looks like you're going way past the useful range with this loop. Suppose `j` is 999 and `n` is 1,000,000. Then `prime_array` is going to have keys as high as 999,000,000 even though you only care about keys from 0 to 1,000,000.

Try limiting your assignments to values below n.

```
        for k in range(2*j, n + 1, j):
            prime_array[k] = 0
```